How to add the long dash some websites use to seperate different sections?
The only thing I was able to figure out was to use a bunch of minus symbols but that doesn't necessarilly look pleasing to the eye. I can't seem to figure this out. I would really appreciate it someone helps me out with this :)
The type of line I am talking about..

Horizontal rule or border.

Your hunch was right--never use text (including whitespace characters) as a formatting or design element.
